# What is "chin-tu" (spelling may be incorrrect) place of interest in Vietnam?

Tags: vietnam

My kid asked vietnamese friend about what is his favourite place of interest in Vietnam and he said "chin-tu". Forgot to ask what is it :) Now googling and can't find anything like this! Found that "chin" may be mean "nine" I found "Nine Holy Cannons", but the name of this object looks different in vietnamese.

Any ideas what it could be?

**UPDATE**

Friend said, it was A HOLIDAY.

Can you hint what holiday it can be?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What other information besides the name do you have? We don't know if it's an artifact, a building, a beach, a garden, a neighborhood, a type of business, etc. so guessing correctly at something that might be someone's favorite something does not seem answerable in our Q&A format.

Comment: You said *object*. What are you referring to? Are you looking for a place, a site, a monument? What type of thing is it?

Comment: I don't know what is it. It should be touristic object or place. If you know Vietnam, but don't know what is it, hence some mistake appeared somewhere.

Comment: @choster I don't ask someone's favourite something, I am asking is there something well known and popular with this name, something like Tour Eiffel in Paris.

Comment: No idea then. I did go through the entire length of Vietnam this year, visiting nearly at points of interest in National Geographics and Fodor's books and that does not sound like anything I remember.

Comment: I'm Vietnamese and I've never heard of Chin-tu as a famous place. Probably wrong spelling.
May be Chan Tu is correct

Comment: Seems like you need to get your child to find out more, rather than asking a hopelessly vague question here.

Answer (score 5):

[Cần Thơ](https://www.tripadvisor.com.my/Attraction_Review-g303942-d455150-Reviews-Cai_Rang_Floating_Market-Can_Tho_Mekong_Delta.html) almost same "chin-tu" phonetically.

> none are bigger, or more popular than the Can Tho’s Cai Rang **Floating
>   Market.**

[Tuần Châu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu%E1%BA%A7n_Ch%C3%A2u) island

> Covered by pine forests, Tuần Châu island has an area of 2.2 km² and
>   to the east and south are two man-made beaches endowed with very
>   white, fine sand. Nowadays, Tuần Châu Island is **one of the most
>   touristic destinations** in Hạ Long.

I hope it is correct ;)

Comment: What about **HOLIDAY**? Is there any holiday of festival in Vietnam with this name?

Comment: Cần Thơ definitely isn't any close to *chin-tu*